# $f(x) = (x^2 -1)^2(a_0 x^3+a_1 x^2 + a_2 x + a_3 )$ $f'(x)$ has exactly $3$ distinct real roots and $f''(x)$ has two distinct real roots. Find $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, continuity, rolles-theorem

Can we get a function in the following form and properties ?

$f(x) = (x^2 -1)^2(a_0 x^3+a_1 x^2 + a_2 x + a_3 )$ $f'(x)$ has exactly $3$ distinct real roots and $f''(x)$ has two distinct real roots.

Can anyone help me to find a function in that way ?

By using calculus , we can say for sure $f'(x)$ will have at least three distinct real roots and $f''(x)$ has at least two distinct real roots.

But I am finding a function in that form such that $f'(x)$ has exactly $3$ distinct real roots and $f''(x)$ has exactly $2$ distinct real roots.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look . @Leo

Comment: Hint: $\;f'$ has degree $6$ in general, so for it to have $3$ distinct real roots one of them must be a double root.

Comment: so $f''(x)$ will have at least three distinct real roots if $f'(x)$ has exactly three distinct real roots. So we do not have such function. Am I right ?@dxiv

Comment: @sani No, but $f''$ will also need to have a double root.

Comment: no take the function $f(x)=(x^3+1)(x^2-1)^2$. f'(x) and f'''(x) have exactly three distinct real roots. f''(x) has exactly 3 roots.

Comment: @sani That $f$ cannot be a solution since $f''$ does not have a double root. Note that for $f'$ and $f''$ to each have a double root is a necessary condition, though not a sufficient one. You did not say what the source of the problem was, or whether you have reasons to expect a "nice" solution.